# Jquery dialog is not working second time of input button in mvc 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i am facing problem with jquery popup dialog,when i submit first time input button click is fire but when i click second time input button there is no response why,help me to solve this problem,i am giving my code below.

```js
 <script "text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
        $('#dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 300,
            height:200,
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            open: function(event, ui) {
                $(this).load("@Url.Action("Idex", "Home")");
            },
            buttons: {
                "Close": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
         $("#opener").click(function () {
             $("#dialog").dialog("open");
         });
     });
    </script>
```

```html
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog" >Please wait</div>
<input id="opener" type="submit" class="myForm" value="Index" />
```

Comment: Try change input type button, or use button element, Also, if don't want to change input type submit, instead of "click" use "submit" event.

Comment: Thank you for reply sir,i am using instead of input button,i had used button element and i had used click type also,it shows same

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 300,
        height:200,
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        open: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).load("@Url.Action("Idex", "Home")");
        },
        buttons: {
            "Close": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
     $(document).on("click" "#opener",function () {
         $("#dialog").dialog("open");
     });


<button id="opener" type="button">Open Dialog</button>
```

Comment: thanks for reply sir,In this code not fire first time also,may i know i want to change any changes of input button